# Не отправляется имейл с сайта

Tags: python-3.x, django

views.py

```
@csrf_protect
def home(request):
slider = Slider.objects.all().order_by('id')
products = Product.objects.filter(is_active=True,      is_main=True).order_by('product__created')[::-1][:5]
news = reversed(NewsBlog.objects.all().order_by('newsdate'))

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OrderIndex(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        message = """
        Письмо от {0}
        Тел: {1}, почта:{2} 
        {3}""".format(cd['customer_name'],
                      cd['customer_phone'],
                      cd['customer_email'],
                      cd['comment'])
        print(message)
        try:
            send_mail(
                'Заказ настенного пано',
                message,
                cd['customer_email'],
                ['napr.sa@gmail.com'],
            )
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('index.html')
else:
    form = OrderIndex()
return render(request, 'index.html', locals())
```

template.html

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'home' %}">{% csrf_token %}
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="form-group">
   {{form}}
</div><!--/extra-->
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Отменить</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" formaction="{% url 'home' %}">Отправить</button>
</div>
</form>
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
```

Почему форма не сохраняется в базе и почта не отправляется? В сеттингс тоже добавил настройки

Comment: Вы никак не проверяете случай, когда form не is_valid

Comment: Великолепно! спасибо большое! 8)